# How to store mutiple time in django fields?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a situation like this where I have to store multiple values for a single row. For example, let us say I am creating a doctor's appointment model to store the doctor's name and available timing for that particular doctor.

> doctor_name  |  available_timing
>
> ABC         |   7:00-11:00, 17:00-22:00

I am thinking about using JSON field like this

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField

class DoctorAppointment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)
    available_timing = models.JSONField()
```

Is there any better approach to deal with a problem like this?

Answer (score 0):

You should then use Array type or create a separate table and set there OneToMany relation, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create just another one model for this (this is not necessary, if you don't have specific code rules), you can simple store array of values as a string in CharField.

```
import ast    
timings = ['20:10-20:50', '21:30-22:00']
timings_str = str(timings)
#data saving code
```

When you need to extract array from string

```
ast.literal_eval(timings_str)
```

Note, that in case like this, you will have limited possibilities to filter values in a easy way, but there always are possibility to use regular expressions.